# How to solve a WWW/NonWWW Header Check: FAILED

Tags: google-search-console

I ran a duplicate checker for my website and got the following message

> WWW/NonWWW Header Check: FAILED Your site is not returning a 301
>   redirect from www to non-www or vice versa. This means that Google may
>   cache both versions of your site, causing sitewide duplicate content
>   penalties.

Is this something that i should be worried about and if so how should i fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be worried about it, allot of sites are configured that way and google knows that.

However you can still add this if you want to be safe and send your visitors and google always go to example.com instead of www.example.com

Add this to your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```